# How can I copy the text to the clipboard while using spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, copy-paste, clipboard

I know that on emacs I can install the `xclip` package in order to be able to copy text to the system clipboard... With the `xclip` package installed and adding the following to my `.emacs` file, I can copy the text inside emacs and paste it into another program.

```
(xclip-mode 1)
```

So far everything is fine. However, on spacemacs I'm struggling to make it work... I know I need to edit the `.spacemacs` file in order to make it work. But if I install the `xclip` package and change my `user-config` function to the following:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration for user code:
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs startup, after layer
configuration.
Put your configuration code here, except for variables that should be set
before packages are loaded."
  (xclip-mode 1)
)
```

It doesn't work, if I try to copy text with `yy` (vim keybindings) it won't get to the system clipboard. What am I missing? What do I need to do in order to use `xclip` correctly on spacemacs?

Comment: Which OS are you using? Because , as far as I know, Spacemacs should copy to clipboard by default (e.g. when using `yy`).

Comment: @dalanicolai I'm using Ubuntu 20.04...

Comment: I am on Fedora and copy to clipboard works out of the box on X11 as well as on Wayland, I guess this should be the default behavior on Ubuntu also. Maybe you could ask in the [Spacemacs gitter channel](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs).

Comment: My experience is the same as @dalanicolai.  Copying worked out of the box with `yy`.  I don't even have xclip on my system right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution in a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52297498/14739472)... If I add xclip to the `dotspacemacs-additional-packages` on the `.spacemacs` file as the following:

```
dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(xclip)
```

And then I leave the `user-config` function as it was in my original question it works fine and anything I copy inside spacemacs will get to the system clipboard:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration for user code:
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs startup, after layer
configuration.
Put your configuration code here, except for variables that should be set
before packages are loaded."
  (xclip-mode 1)
)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, copying to the clipboard should probably work by default. If it does not work out of the box, then there is probably something wrong with your setup so that you need this workaround. Have you tried starting Emacs from the terminal with the `--debug-init` flag (or similarly restart from within Spacemacs using `SPC q d`)?

Comment: @dalanicolai I'm new to the emacs world in general... I really didn't do much with config files besides installing emacs and spacemacs. I've even tried erasing my spacemacs folder and getting it from the original git repository again, could it be that the last github version has a bug? The clipboard wasn't working on a fresh install...

Comment: Okay, that sounds like you probably did things right then. So maybe can you check if you are using the develop branch? Otherwise, I have no idea what is going on there. I am not aware of any known issues that seem related to this behavior.

Comment: @dalanicolai I'm using the master branch currently... I've tried switching to the develop branch but the problem remains if I take out the `xclip` from my `.spacemacs` file the way I did on my answer...

Comment: Okay, that is strange, but so then nice to have the workaround. Also, somewhat confusingly, you really should be using the develop branch, which, for 'dubious' historic reasons, is the well maintained and recommended branch. There are plans to get rid of that old master branch, and make the current develop branch the new master branch. But for now... reallly use the develop branch (and also better ask Spacemacs questions in [its gitter channel](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs/) first).